# How to export heterogenous arrays to csv

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, narray

Basically what im trying to do is export np.arrays to a .csv file where my data can be stored neatly. I've tried doing this code, but it doesn't work as i would like to.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

T11= np.array([1, 2, 3])
T21= np.array([4, 5, 6])
T31= np.array([7, 8, 9, 10])
T41= np.array([11, 12, 13, 14])
T51= np.array([15])

Tx=[T11,T21,T31,T41,T51]

Tx1=pd.DataFrame.transpose(Tx)



df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(Tx1),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'])
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

The code gives me this errors, but I don't know how to fix them

`'list' object has no attribute 'dtypes'`

`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 1), indices imply (5, 5)`

I'd really like my output to be something like:

| a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 11 | 15 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 | 12 |  |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 13 |  |
|  |  | 10 | 14 |  |

Comment: `Tx1=pd.DataFrame.transpose(Tx)`  -> `Tx1 = pd.DataFrame(Tx).transpose()` or shorter `Tx1 = pd.DataFrame(Tx).T`? (You have to build a dataframe before transposing it -- I guess it's a typo?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([T11,T21,T31,T41,T51], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f']).T
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=True)
```